# Quel est le contraire de consécutivement ?

Tags: adverbes, conjonctions, antonyme

Quel est le contraire de consécutivement à ? Exemple : consécutivement à l'action A, je ferai l'action B...

J'ai pensé à précédemment mais je ne suis pas sûr que ce soit le plus approprié...

Merci !

Comment: Peut-être qu'**inverse** au lieu de **contraire** aurait évité le malentendu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

« Consécutivement à l'action A » implique une conséquence logique à l'action B qui en découle.

Le contraire de cette expression peut être :

> Quel que soit le résultat de l'action A, je ferai l'action B.

ou bien :

> Je ferai l'action B, même si je ne réalise pas l'action A.

qui peut se simplifier en :

> Je ferai l'action B.

---

S'il est question uniquement de l'ordre des réalisations des deux actions, on peut utiliser :

> Préalablement à l'action A, je ferai l'action B.

Comment: Ce n'est pas vraiment dans ce sens là que ma question se voulait... C'est plutôt de trouver "l'équivalent" à consécutivement dans le cas d'une action se déroulant non pas après mais avant

Comment: @MysteryGuy: J'ai ajouté une réponse.

Comment: Est-ce que "Antérieurement à l'action A, je ferai l'action B." fonctionne ?

Comment: @Lulucmy: Oui, c'est acceptable.